# Search for Arabic text ignoring diacritics, alef hamza differences, and kashida in SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

Well, I have a table with an Arabic column which may contains variant forms of the same word in multiple rows, for example the word "أسمى" might be in the following forms:

1- with diacritics: "أَسْمَى"

2- with changing the last letter of "ى" into "ي" so it would be like "أسمي"

3- with kashida or "ـ" in some part of the word so it would possibly be "أسمــى"

4-with varient forms of alef hamza (أ - إ - ا - ء), so it might be "اسمى" or "إسمى"

5- any combination of the former cases, i.e diacritics and kashida

and I'm looking for a way to store these values in the database (actually I need a solution for SQL Server), and to retrieve them regardless of these differences.

I found that I should use an Arabic collation like this arabic_ci_ai but this collation only helped me in sorting out the problems number (1 and 2)

In addition I considered using a fulltext index on the column, but this has its drawbacks and it doesn't provide full solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I need a solution for SQL and another one for oracle" makes little sense. SQL is a language used in many database systems, including Oracle. Do you mean sql server, mysql or another product? Please add database tags.

Comment: thank you for you comment i made edit to my question :)

Answer (score 1):

[Arabic Case Insensitive In Database Systems: How To Solve Alef With and Without Hamza Problem](https://ahmedspace.com/arabic-case-insensitive-in-database-systems-how-to-solve-alef-with-and-without-hamza-problem/)

## update:

The link above is broken so here is the same article on Medium by Ahmed Essam
https://ahmedessamdev.medium.com/arabic-case-insensitive-in-database-systems-how-to-solve-alef-with-and-without-hamza-problem-c54ee6d40bed